# regex split comma separated string

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I split by fields below (this is sql format)? 
Previously I use to just split by ', ' the problem it fails if that character sequence is within the quotes. 
Unfortunately I also can't split by quotes because the numbers don't have any.

```
mystring = "(1, 'data, ', 'data_two, ', 'Test 34', '', 'gb', 1, '1')"
mystring.split(', ')
```

I need to get

```
'1'
'data'
'data_two, '
'Test 34'
''
'gb'
'1'
'1'
```

Comment: My bad fixed forgot the quotes

Comment: check out the answer below... please approve if this works for you

Comment: Why don't you use [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), since it is designed to handle strings like that?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to split apart a SQL response, use an ORM like Sequel, to talk to the DBM. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Why do you want to strip the comma on the second item but not the third?

Answer (score 1):

If you strip the parens, you can coerce it into being parseable using `CSV` with options.

```
CSV.parse_line(mystring[1..-2], {:col_sep=>", ", :quote_char=>"'"})

 => ["1", "data, ", "data_two, ", "Test 34", "", "gb", "1", "1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.split(/,/).map{|x| x.gsub(/[()\']/,'').strip}
 => ["1", "data", "", "data_two", "", "Test 34", "", "gb", "1", "1"]
```

Comment: Because there could be a comma in between quotes like there is in the second item

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

```
irb(main):001:0> mystring
=> "(1, 'data, ', 'data_two, ', 'Test 34', '', 'gb', 1, '1')"
irb(main):002:0> mystring.scan(/(?:'(?:\\.|[^'])*'|[^,' ])+/)
=> ["(1", "'data, '", "'data_two, '", "'Test 34'", "''", "'gb'", "1", "'1')"]
```

Or, if you need quotes and braces to be removed, then:

```
irb(main):003:0> mystring.scan(/([^', ()]+)|'([^']*)'/).flatten.compact
=> ["1", "data, ", "data_two, ", "Test 34", "", "gb", "1", "1"]
```

This will match any non quote/brace/comma/space characted word, or anything inside of single 'quotes'. (Note, that escape sequence (`\x`) is not accounted in second example unlike first one. But it may be that you don't need such complications.)